# Агрегирующие функции в SQL запросах

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день.

В базе MS SQL Server 2008 нужно выполнить запрос,содержащий функцию `COUNT()` и фильтрующий по столбцу `Chanel`.

```sql
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT SR, COUNT(Route_SR) AS Work_base, Chanel
FROM         dbo.Sensus
GROUP BY SR, Route_SR, Chanel
HAVING      (Route_SR = 'да') AND (Chanel = 'маленький магазин' OR
                      Chanel = 'большой магазин')
ORDER BY SR
```

Проблема в том, что при таком запросе выводится количество записей в разрезе SR и Chanel. Мне же нужно поличить только два столбца SR и COUNT(Route_SR), но выполнив фильтрацию (Chanel = 'маленький магазин' OR Chanel = 'большой магазин').

Запрос:

```sql
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT SR, COUNT(Route_SR) AS Work_base 
FROM         dbo.Sensus
GROUP BY SR, Route_SR
HAVING      (Route_SR = 'да') AND (Chanel = 'маленький магазин' OR
                      Chanel = 'большой магазин')
ORDER BY SR
```

выдает ошибку, т.к. `Chanel` не содержется в `GROUP BY`.

Как получить нуждые данные средствами SQL?

Answer (score 6):

Условие `AND (Chanel = 'маленький магазин' OR Chanel = 'большой магазин')` надо использовать не в `HAVING`, а в `WHERE`. Вообще все условия надо перенести в `WHERE`. `HAVING` вообще принципиально отличается тем, что работает именно с агрегированными данными, зачем его использовать как критерий отбора?

```sql
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT SR, COUNT(Route_SR) AS Work_base 
FROM dbo.Sensus  
WHERE (Route_SR = 'да') AND (Chanel = 'маленький магазин' OR Chanel = 'большой магазин') 
GROUP BY SR, Route_SR 
ORDER BY SR
```